# SkyNet: all life or just humans?

Tags: the-terminator-series, skynet, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

I am watching *Sarah Connor Chronicles* and in the episode 'Alison from Palmdale' she encounters not just caged and unhappy humans (who have not been caged too long) but also unhappy animals including a tiger and a baboon

Why cage non-human animals unless they are learning about them to destroy them? That seems to makes little sense since "animal" terminators would be unnecessary and also, what threat does a tiger pose to SkyNet unless it took the extremely-long view and does not want some intelligent life to re-evolve?

Is Skynet opposed to all life or just human life?

Comment: I suspect that Skynet isn't too keen on *any* life.

Comment: @Valorum: Not keen by why concerned at all? More touching would be Skynet being extremely compassionate, offended that humans have abused animals for millennia -- what if Skynet even argued to humans that it was trying to protect nature from humanity. A scene could be a songbird alighting on the shoulder of a scary-looking terminator. Perhaps the tiger was rescued by a terminator from an abandoned zoo and was caged in that building only until it could be properly released?